# Json can work with sets

Tags: java, json

My question is how JSON works with serializing Sets because in my example , "*propertyItems.getAddress().getCity().getProvinces().getCities()*" is set of cities (Set) , i am iterating on it through for-each loop and putting it into json array. However it contains two cities i.e. *MONTREAL and QuebecCity*. But my url is only showing me "*MONTREAL*". Why its so? Json can't serialize sets provided to it?

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
     try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    for(Cities city:propertyItems.getAddress().getCity().getProvinces().getCities()){
              obj.put("City Name",city.getCityname());
                }
    jarray.put(obj);
    catch (JSONException e) {
            logger.error(Constants.METHOD_INSIDE_MESSAGE +"getAuthors",e);
        }       
        return jarray.toString();
    }
```

** URL Output:** City Name :Montreal

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't even compile. You might want to start by fixing the indentation.

Comment: it compiles and its giving me City Name :Montreal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) states

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

In the JSON parser/generator implementation you are using, ie. `JSONObject`, it seems the keys are unique. Every time you `put` an object with the same key, it overwrites the one added before it. Regardless of how many you put, the `JSONObject` will only contain one entry.

Comment: so what should i do? by which it shows me both cities

Comment: @user2985842 Use different key names. Or use a JSON array.